# Speed limitations when importing files from .zip archive

Tags: performance-tuning, import, compression

I have .m files with a total size of ~500 MB. Their import is really fast, within less than 1 second. In contrast, I may pack them into a .zip archive. The importing then is much slower, ~20 s. Switching to tar.gz does not help.

Is it possible to compress them and still have a reasonable speed of importing, or the speed decrease is fundamental?

Comment: It shouldn't be fundamental, but in general I find that `Import` runs the gamut from really fast to really slow depending on what you're importing. You might want to try using filesystem-level compression, if that's an option for you?

Comment: @eyorble : I want to make a repository including the compressed .m files. Probably, south type of compression would not work in my case.

Comment: What makes the .m files so large? If it's some kind of data, it might make sense to store those in a separate binary file, maybe even .mx (if the restrictions of .mx work for you). That would likely lead to smaller files & faster imports at the same time

Comment: @LukasLang : yes, they are basically just huge tables. It looks like these files are already in "MX" format, just the extension is ".m".

Comment: @JohnTaylor why are you saying "it looks like"? How exactly are you importing the files? (both in the compressed & uncompressed case)

Comment: @LukasLang : I imported them using "MX". Yes, the structure is the binary file.